# How do I access PostgreSQL by both socket and port?

Tags: postgresql, sockets, passwords, psql

I have started a PostgreSQL process as follows:

```
pg_ctl start -w -D /path/to/data -l /path/to/log -o "-F -k /path/to/unix/socket -h ''"
```

(alternatively `-h '*'` instead of `-h ''`)

> Aside, references for [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pg-ctl.html) (the outer function) and [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-postgres.html) (the -o parameter)

and created a user (with password) and database:

```
createuser -P admin
createdb -O admin db
```

I can connect to the database via the unix socket (does not trigger a password prompt):

```
psql -h /path/to/unix/socket -U admin -d dbname
```

but connecting via the TCP port fails:

```
psql -h localhost -U admin -d dbname
Password for user snaprevs_admin:
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin"
```

What do I need to change so that both the unix socket and TCP connections work as expected?

Comment: 1) Why not just use the system script to start postgres? 2) Connection access is controlled via [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). That is where this controlled. Best guess `local`(socket) `auth` is set to `trust` and `host`(tcp/ip) is set to `md5` or `scram-sha-256` password `auth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are performing a custom `pg_ctl` launch, you should check that there isn't a default service already running. If there is it will consume the default TCP port.

To stop the default service and prevent it from starting on next boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable postgresql --now
```

If you only want to stop it temporarily:

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

You should now be able to stop and re-start your custom service (with `-h '*'`), then log in over TCP.